# Как узнать, какой код более оптимизированный(c#)

Tags: c#

Допустим у меня есть две программы выполняющие одно и то-же действие, но с отличающими кодами. Как узнать какой из этих кодов более оптимизирован, какой меньше памяти использует, меньше выч-ой мощности и т д. Слышал есть сайты для этого, никак не могу найти

Comment: прогнать код через https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: @PashaPash думаю надо в качестве ответа оформить.

Comment: Можно использовать встроенное средство (не помню точно с какой вижлы оно встроено, но в 17ой точно есть) - Memory profiler